# Join several dataframes together into one in R

Tags: r, dataframe, inner-join

Working in R. I have 9 dataframes that all share a common ID that I want to join together. Normally I would use inner_join with just 2 dfs, but with 9 it's a little more complex (and I'm not great at R). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can bring it into a `list` and then use `inner_join` with `reduce`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
lst1 <- list(df1, df2, df3, ...., dfn)
```

If the object names have a pattern i.e. `df` followed by some digits, it can be converted to a `list` more easily

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^df\\d+$'))
reduce(lst1, inner_join, by = 'ID')
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done with `merge` and `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'ID'), lst1)
```

Comment: I see that this creates a list, but I'm not sure I understand how to combine everything in the list to create a new dataframe... You lost me at the reduce portion

Comment: @mrm081 that is the `reduce` step doing

Comment: I don't understand what is supposed to go inside the first ( ) after function and what is supposed to go inside ( , after merge

Comment: @mrm081 if you have datasets `df1`, `df2`, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, then `lst1 <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9)` and then use `reduce(lst1, inner_join, by = 'ID')`

Comment: Ah. I did that. Sorry for the confusion, you're great!